# Nested class in ASP.Net with no primary key

Tags: asp.net, database, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to have a column on a table be a class but whenever I try to build the migration

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialDB
```

it returns

> Error: The entity type 'Settings' requires a primary key to be defined.

How can I put a class as a column in a table and not have it treated like a row, that needs a primary key

Comment: ***What*** database system are you working with? Typically, relational databases do not support columns of a "complex" type - a column can only be one of the basic atomic types - int, string, bool, date etc.

Comment: @marc_s I started working with databases 2 days ago, I'm usually on the client side. How can I check? Alternatively, I used this sample https://github.com/azure-samples/dotnetcore-sqldb-tutorial

Comment: That tutorial is in fact for an Azure SQL database - a relational database, that supports only the basic datatypes like int, float, money, datetime, varchar for its columns. You cannot define an entire class as a column

Comment: @marc_s okay, so I assume I'd want to use ForeignKeys to link a query from another database. I see when I give the child object a Foreign key and the parent object an object of the child type it the migration builder automatically adds a Table for the child items. However it doesn't automatically query for them. How do/Can I set it to query for the child when ever the object is referenced?

Comment: That's a whole different separate question, really .... can you update your question to show the model classes you're using? Do you have e.g.  a `Customer` class which was supposed to contain an `Address` class as a property? Show us the two classes - then someone might be able to show you how to do this "properly" in a relational model

Comment: @marc_s Understood and thanks for the help. I'm trying something out right now and if that works I'll make a self answer with an appropriately edited, if it fails I'll just update the question. Again thanks for the help

Comment: @AvishaiDernis Were you able to successfully resolve your issue?

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT Yes, I use a ForiegnKey and store it in another Table. It's kind of a half solution so idk if I want to self answer with that